# Fourier transform of $1/x^2$ given by Mathematica

Tags: distribution-theory, fourier-transform

Mathematica gives $-k \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \text{sgn}(k)$ as the Fourier transform of $1/x^2$ (i.e., the result of the command `FourierTransform[1/x^2, x, k]`). And the Fourier transform of $-k \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \text{sgn}(k)$ is $1/x^2$ (`FourierTransform[-k Sqrt[Pi/2] Sign[k], k, x]`). I found this by chance while playing with Mathematica, but I cannot understand the result. The definition of Fourier transform $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-ikx} dx$ does not converge for the functions, and even Mathematica reports that the integrals does not converge. I read the documentation of `FourierTransform` but could not find any relevant information. In what sense are they Fourier transform of each other?

I found an almost same question ([What does the Fourier transform of $1/x^2$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837046/what-does-the-fourier-transform-of-1-x2-mean)), but the answers looks not so complete. The answers mention "tempered distribution" and so I read some basic materials about it, but $1/x^2$ is not a tempered distribution as some comments on the answers already pointed. Is the notion of the Fourier transform of tempered distributions really relevant to my question?

Comment: According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional), $1/x^2$ is defined in this context as the distributional derivative $$ -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log|x|. $$ It also refers to two books that should contain the derivation of this transform, namely [Erdélyi (1954)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#CITEREFErd%C3%A9lyi1954), and [Kammler (2000)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#CITEREFKammler2000).

Comment: @Sobi Thank you. Then the notation $1/x^2$ should not be interpreted as a usual function $\mathbb{R} \setminus 0 \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto 1/x^2$. The distribution you gave is different from the usual fuction $1/x^2$ in the sense of [equality between distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Functions_as_distributions). Am I right?

Comment: They should coincide in the distributional sense, I think.

Comment: @Sobi Do you mean $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \phi(x) dx = \left< -\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \log|x|, \phi \right>$ with test function $\phi$?

Comment: I don't feel confident enough to answer, but I would guess that $$ -\left\langle \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\log|x|, \phi \right\rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{x^2} \phi(x) \, dx.$$

Comment: @Sobi if $\phi(0)\neq 0$ then the integral in the RHS does not converge, this would work if instead of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ we had an odd function like $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa Good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, the function $\frac{1}{x^2}$ cannot be identified as a tempered distribution in the usual way as it is not locally integrable.

Here the symbol "$\frac{1}{x^2}$" has another meaning in the context of tempered distributions, which is formalized by the concept of [Hadamard finite-part integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization).

That is we define a linear map
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{x^2}:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})&\to \mathbb{R}\\ 
\varphi&\mapsto \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\left[\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x^2}dx-2\frac{\varphi(0)}{\varepsilon}\right]
\end{align*}
The function is well defined: since $\varphi$ is smooth by the mean value theorem we may write 
$$\varphi(x)=\varphi(0)+x\varphi'(\xi(x)),\qquad \xi(x)\in [0,x] $$
so that 
\begin{align*}\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\varphi(x)}{x^2}dx-2\frac{\varphi(0)}{\varepsilon}&=\varphi(0)\left(\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{1}{x^2}dx-\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\right)+\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\varphi'(\xi(x))}{x}dx=\\ 
&=\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\varphi'(\xi(x))}{x}dx
 \end{align*}
and applying mean value again, with $\varphi'(\xi(x))=\varphi'(0)+\xi(x)\varphi''(\eta(x))$,
$$\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\varphi'(\xi(x))}{x}dx=\varphi'(0)\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\varphi''(\eta(x))\frac{\xi(x)}{x}dx=\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\varphi''(\eta(x))\frac{\xi(x)}{x}dx $$
 Since $\xi(x)\in [0,x]$ for all $x$, we have $\frac{\xi(x)}{x}\in [0,1]$ and so the last integral converges as $\varepsilon \to 0$, so that 
$$\frac{1}{x^2}(\varphi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\varphi''(\eta(x))\frac{\xi(x)}{x}dx $$

Now to prove that the map $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a tempered distribution, suppose $\varphi_n\to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Then in particular $\varphi_n''(\eta(x))\to 0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and so
$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2}(\varphi_n)\right|\leq \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\varphi_n''(\eta(x))|dx\to 0$$

and therefore its Fourier transform is well-defined as the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution.

Comment: How to extend this reasoning for any natural number $n$ to find the Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{x^n}$?

Answer (score 1):

I will here use the non-unitary, angular frequency [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) defined as
$$\hat{u}(\nu) = \mathcal{F}\{ u(x) \} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x) \, e^{-i \nu x} \, dx.$$

By first definition of the distribution $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and then [rule 106](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms)
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{x^2} \right\}
= \mathcal{F}\left\{ \left( -\frac{1}{x} \right)' \right\}
= -i\nu \, \mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}.
$$

Here $\frac{1}{x}$ is defined as the unique odd distribution satisfying $x \frac{1}{x} = 1.$ Therefore, by [rule 107](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms), we have
$$
2\pi \, \delta(\nu)
= \mathcal{F}\left\{ 1 \right\}
= \mathcal{F}\left\{ x \frac{1}{x} \right\}
= i\frac{d}{d\nu} \mathcal{F} \left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}
$$
so
$$
\mathcal{F} \left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\} = -i \, 2\pi H(\nu) + C
$$
for some constant $C.$ Here $H$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Since $\frac{1}{x}$ is odd so must be $\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}.$ Therefore $C = i \, \pi$ and
$$
\mathcal{F} \left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\} 
= -i \, 2\pi H(\nu) + i \pi
= -i \pi \operatorname{sign}(\nu),
$$
where $\operatorname{sign}$ is the [signature function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Thus,
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{x^2} \right\}
= -i\nu \, \mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}
= -i\nu \, \left( -i\pi \operatorname{sign}(\nu) \right)
= -\pi \, \nu \, \operatorname{sign}(\nu)
= -\pi \, |\nu|.
$$

Comment: How to extend this reasoning for any natural number $n$ to find the Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{x^n}$?

Comment: You missed to add a constant multiple of the Dirac Delta at zero in the final result.

Comment: @DrPotato. I don't think that I have missed any term. What makes you think that I have missed a term?

Comment: @DrPotato. Since $\frac{1}{x^n} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ (did I get this right?) one has
$$\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{x^n} \right\} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} (i\nu)^{n-1} \mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{x} \right\}.$$

Comment: The correct result is $2\pi\delta(0)-\pi|\nu|$

Comment: @Anixx. $\delta(0)$ is rubbish.