# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix}/x^2\ dx$

Tags: integration

how to calculate integral of following function over infinity ?
i tried to solve this in ever program and ask some of my teacher they can't answer please help me.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

That integral does not exist. There are various ways of "interpreting" some divergent integrals - Cauchy principal value, summation methods,  whatever. None of them work here; the singularity at the origin is "like" $1/t^2$, no cancellation available. The integral really really does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This a stretch, but perhaps you started with an expression that was meant to be interpreted only in a [weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution) sense such as
$$G(x,x')=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k(x-x')}}{k^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi}$$
in which case we might say that
$$G(x,x')=-\tfrac{1}{2}\lvert x-x'\rvert\text{,}$$
i.e.,
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}k}}{k^2}\mathrm{d}k\text{"$=$"}-\pi\text{.}$$

Comment: I know what a weak solution to a differential equation is. I don't see how citing a link to that converts a clearly divergent integral to $-|x-x'|$.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this with a [regulator-based approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327812/limit-approach-to-finding-1234-ldots) (see also [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/)). Let

$$ f(\eta) = \mathrm{e}^{-\eta} (1 - 2 \eta) $$

be our regulator. Then

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}}{x^2} f\left(\left(\frac{2 \varepsilon}{x}\right)^2\right) \mathrm{d}x \\
&\stackrel{!}{=} \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}}{x^2} f\left(\left(\frac{2 \varepsilon}{x}\right)^2\right) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \left( -\frac{4 \pi \varepsilon^2}{3} {_0}F_2\left(;2,\frac{5}{2};\varepsilon^2\right) - \pi {_0}F_2\left(;1,\frac{3}{2};\varepsilon^2\right) + \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \varepsilon} \left({_0}F_2\left(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\varepsilon^2\right) - {_0}F_2\left(;-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\varepsilon^2\right) \right)\right) \\
&= 0 - \pi + 0 \\
&= -\pi
\end{align}

where where ${_p}F_q(a;b;z)$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).

Comment: I misread something, sorry.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No problem. To be clear, the original integral is of course divergent. I'm talking about its [regularized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics)) value (hence the word 'regulator').

Comment: @user76284: As David C Ulrich pointed out, the integral does not exists in the sense of Lebesgue, not even in the sense of distributions. $u=1/x^2$ is understood to [act](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2900524/121671) on $\mathcal{S}$ as
$$u:\phi\mapsto \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\Big(\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{\phi(y)}{y^2}\,dy -2\frac{\phi(0)}{\varepsilon}\Big)$$

In that sense, [its Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2900652/121671)is given by $\widehat{u}(\phi)=-\pi\int\operatorname{sign}(x)x\phi(x)$